# Calendar.Month gives wrong output

Tags: java, calendar

I have been using `java.util` for all date and calendar representations. But I am facing a strange problem here. `Calendar.MONTH`, `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH`, etc all give wrong outputs. But when I use `Calendar.getTime()`, I get the right output. What might be the problem?

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println(rightNow.MONTH);
        System.out.println(rightNow.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        System.out.println(rightNow.YEAR);
        System.out.println(rightNow.getTime());
    }
}
```

And the output for the same is:

```
2
5
1
Tue Jan 22 10:31:44 GMT+05:30 2013
```

Comment: When using Java Calendar, be wary that things that you would intuitively expect to be 1-indexed, such as month, are in fact 0-indexed. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH

Comment: I dont know Java at all, but those look like positional constants...

Comment: The `Calendar` class has a range of design problems with it, you’ve struck just one of them. While using it in 2013 was reasonable, it was replaced the following year by `ZonedDateTime` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). So never use `Calendar` again now.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 8):

```
    System.out.println(rightNow.MONTH);
    System.out.println(rightNow.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    System.out.println(rightNow.YEAR);
    System.out.println(rightNow.getTime());
```

You are printing Calendar constant values.

If you want values, you need to do `get....`

Example:

```
    System.out.println(rightNow.get(Calendar.MONTH));
```

Read [Calendar javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29) for more information.

Comment: I am doing mCalendar.setDate(java.util.Date) but still giving me wrong Month value

Comment: Actually this is problem with Java Calendar API the first month is 0 not 1 :-)

Comment: If you print out the first month January it will print 0 not 1

Answer (score 6):

Calendar.MONTH doesn't return the current month. It is a constant whose value is 2.

From the source:

```
public final static int MONTH = 2;
```

It is for use as a parameter in Calendar's get method

```
public int get(int field) {...}
```

The design of Calendar is from the early days of Java, when many of today's conventions were different, non-existant, or developing. Oracle (and earlier, Sun), would never let an API like the java.util.Calendar API become part of the standard API today.

And, for completeness, use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) instead of Java's Date and Calendar API's.

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

```
    ZonedDateTime rightNow = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Africa/Cairo"));
    System.out.println(rightNow.getMonth());
    System.out.println(rightNow.getMonthValue());
    System.out.println(rightNow.getDayOfMonth());
    System.out.println(rightNow.getYear());
    System.out.println(rightNow);
```

Output when running just now was:

> ```
> FEBRUARY
> 2
> 15
> 2019
> 2019-02-15T21:15:06.313809+02:00[Africa/Cairo]
> ```

### Don’t use Calendar

The `Calendar` class is confusing and suffers from poor design, so no wonder that you’re wondering. Fortunately it was replaced the year after you asked this quesion by `ZonedDateTime` and other classes in java.time, the modern Java date and time API. So never use `Calendar` again now.

The `Calendar` class was trying to be very general, so instead of a `getMonth` method, etc., it had the notion of *fields* that could be read and set. Since it was designed long before Java had `enum`s, each field had a number and a named constant for that number. So `YEAR` (of era) was 1, `MONTH` was 2, etc. To get the value of the field of a `Calendar` object you were supposed to call the `get` method passing the appropriate named constant, for example `rightNow.get(Calendar.MONTH)`. Using just `rightNow.MONTH` is a regularly repeated mistake. It just gives you the value of the constant, 2.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    out.println("month now= " + (now.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1));
```

OR with GregorianCalender:

```
    GregorianCalendar nu  = new GregorianCalendar();
    int day = nu.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month = (nu.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);  //month +1 because january`==0
    int year= nu.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int hour= nu.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minutes= nu.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

here

Comment: Please wrap all of your code in code blocks. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Thank you for wanting to contribute. As said, we should not use `Calendar` nor `GregorianCalendar` anymore, so frankly, I see helping users how to do that as helping them do what they should not do. Instead I encourage you to learn [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Thanks for giving me that option. I have only just learned the Calendar class and how to use it. I will definitely check out the java.time.