# Someone please explain how Calendar.get(cal.DAY_OF_WEEK) gives correct output while cal.DAY_OF_WEEK is default and not modified?

Tags: java, calendar, dayofweek

I want to get the day for the date. When i set the date in cal.set(year,month-1,day), Sets the values for the calendar fields *YEAR, MONTH, DAY_OF_MONTH, HOUR_OF_DAY, and MINUTE*. Previous values of other fields are retained. Thus, when I do cal.DAY_OF_WEEK, I will get the values which were existing already.
But how does the cal.get(cal.DAY_OF_WEEK) gives the correct value? (As mentioned in java docs, *public int get(int field)* Returns the value of the given calendar field.) I don't understand how passing the integer value in this function  *(as calendar field that too un-modified)* gives the correct output.

```
public static String findDay() {
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.set(2019,1,15);
 System.out.println(cal.toString());
 System.out.println(cal.DAY_OF_WEEK); //7 which is unchanged by cal.set
 System.out.println(cal.get(cal.DAY_OF_WEEK)); //6
 return "";

}
```

Code output:

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Etc/UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transi
tions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2019,MONTH=1,WEEK_OF_YEAR=7,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=15,DAY_OF_YEAR=46,DAY_OF_WEEK=6,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN
_MONTH=3,AM_PM=0,HOUR=11,HOUR_OF_DAY=11,MINUTE=38,SECOND=14,MILLISECOND=374,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]    
7
6
```

Comment: Use up-to-date APIs: `java.time.LocalDateTime` respectively  `java.time.OffsetDateTime` instead of deprecated `java.util.Calendar`.

Comment: `cal.DAY_OF_WEEK`, or better `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK`, is a constant of the class and will never be changed by anything..

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels then explain how come the values differ in cal.toString() and cal.DAY_OF_WEEK, shouldn't both be the same?

Comment: Please see my (community wiki) answer for the details

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Maybe you should post that answer under one of the original questions instead? (This question is being asked regularly.)

Comment: @OleV.V.: perhaps. I answered as a comm wiki since I voted to close this question as well, and I was too lazy to look for a duplicate

Comment: You are using *terrible* date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. Stop torturing yourself with these legacy classes.

Comment: I provided [a new answer to one of the original questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715767/5772882).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's dissect these:

This:

```
System.out.println(cal.toString());
```

prints out the `toString()` for your Calendar object, the state of its fields, and returns this:

> java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Etc/UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transi
>   tions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2019,MONTH=1,WEEK_OF_YEAR=7,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=15,DAY_OF_YEAR=46,DAY_OF_WEEK=6,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN
>   _MONTH=3,AM_PM=0,HOUR=11,HOUR_OF_DAY=11,MINUTE=38,SECOND=14,MILLISECOND=374,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]

And yes, here DAY_OF_WEEK is 6

While this:

```
System.out.println(cal.DAY_OF_WEEK); //7 which is unchanged by cal.set
```

returns the `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` field result, which is a constant and is == to 7.

Finally this:

```
System.out.println(cal.get(cal.DAY_OF_WEEK)); //6
```

returns 6, which is the DAY_OF_WEEK field held by your Calendar object.

Picture your Calendar object (simplified) to look like this:

```
public abstract class Calendar {
    public static int DAY_OF_WEEK = 7;  // a constant that never changes

    // ..... many more fields

    // field name may be different
    private int dayOfWeek = 0; // or some other default value

    public void set(...) {
        // sets the dayOfWeek value
    }

    public int get(int ) {
        if (field == DAY_OF_WEEK) {
            return this.dayOfWeek;
        }

        // .... more code

    }

    public String toString() {
        return .... + "DAY_OF_WEEK:" + dayOfWeek + .....;
    }
}
```

make sense now? There is a hidden dayOfWeek field that you're setting and getting the result of

So this:

```
System.out.println(cal.get(cal.DAY_OF_WEEK));
```

actually returns the `dayOfWeek` private field result

Comment: Thanks a lot :)  This is simply a great explanation!!

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the java doc of `Calendar` class, it clearly mentions what is the purpose of `cal.DAY_OF_WEEK`. It just represents the number of a field and the `get()` method accept the field number and returns its value. You can consider the value of `cal.DAY_OF_WEEK` as an index of an array from which the `get()` method retrieves the value. Please see below the documentation of `get()` method.

```
Returns the value of the given calendar field. In lenient mode,
 * all calendar fields are normalized. In non-lenient mode, all
 * calendar fields are validated and this method throws an
 * exception if any calendar fields have out-of-range values. The
 * normalization and validation are handled by the
 * {@link #complete()} method, which process is calendar
```

Comment: so now I get it, the cal.DAY_OF_WEEK returns an index (which is referred by Calendar  field in docs) for which the data can be fetched by cal.get()

Comment: Yes. It works like that.