# Seting calendar.day_of_month is setting calendar.year

Tags: java, spring, date, calendar, simpledateformat

I have a calendar initially set to 2019-11-01, that i want to set to the first date and the last date of month using the:

```
cal.set(int field,int value)
```

And for the field i use either:

```
Calendar.DATE or Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH
```

But system on sysout shows that it is setting the Calendar.YEAR instead

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(cal.getTime()));

cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),1);
        
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(cal.getTime()));
        
cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(cal.getTime()));
```

Sysout:

> 2019-11-01
>
> 0001-11-01
>
> 0030-11-01

Comment: Java 8, with its java.time API, came out in March 2014. We're in November 2019, more than 5 years later. Stop using te old, obsolete, clunky Calendar and Date classes. Use the java.time API.

Comment: `cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);` and `cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));` - do not call `cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` - that is not correct.

Comment: Somehow a variant of [date and time not working in Alarm Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57743785/date-and-time-not-working-in-alarm-manager)

Comment: Yes, the `Calendar` class has a confusing interface. No wonder people are making such errors. You’re far from the first and not the last either, unfortunately. The good solution (and it is *very* good) is to stop using the `Calendar` class and start using [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead.

Comment: thank you all i will quit this Calendar class

Comment: Congratulations on the decision to quit the `Calendar` class. You may consider helping other readers to do the same by accepting the answer that recommends just that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use

> Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH

NOT

> cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

since the Calendar class have static fields to represents the ID of each field, for example DAY_OF_MONTH = 5
and when you use cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),1) you told the calendar to get the calendar value of DAY_OF_MONTH which is equal to = 1 (you said the cal value = 2-19-11-01), and 1 is the Year, so that you get the year set to 1 instead of the day

use it like:
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);

Comment: This terrible class was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: Yes it is, but I am explaining what is correct in Calendar class @BasilBourque

Answer (score 5):

You can use the java-8 modern date time API [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), stop using the legacy [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) or [util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2019-11-01");

System.out.println(date.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth()));  //2019-11-01
System.out.println(date.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()));   //2019-11-30
```