# How can I create a void function that lists next 13 Friday on 13th

Tags: java, calendar

Guys, i want to create a list of upcoming 13 Fridays on 13th 
how can I do this?

I try this for one Year:

```
  public static void getFridayThirteen() {

    for (int i = 1; i <= 365; i++) {
        if (Calendar.FRIDAY == 13) {
            fridayThirteen = i++;
            System.out.println("Test" + fridayThirteen);
        }
    }
```

but nothing appear in the output.

Comment: Please be more specific

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Similar to (but probably not a strict duplicate of) [Calendar.Month gives wrong output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451872/calendar-month-gives-wrong-output)

Comment: Your code is iterating over numbers (1 through 365), not over days. There is nothing in the code stating that it should start today or tomorrow. And why you get no output: `Calendar.FRIDAY` is a constant representing that day of the week, it’s a confusing design from before Java had enums. The value of the constant happens to be 6 (a bit confusing too since Friday is the 5th day of the ISO week), and since 6 is not equal to 13, the inner of your `if` statement is never executed. My Eclipse clearly tells me so: it underlines those lines and says *Dead code*. Warnings from your IDE are helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can do this is:

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now(); // or the LocalDate.now(ZoneId) overload
int count = 0;
// first set the date to the next Friday first...
ld = ld.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY));
// this will find 10 such dates
while (count < 10) {
    if (isFriday13(ld)) { // implementation shown below
        count++;
        System.out.println(ld);
    }
    ld = ld.plusDays(7); // this set ld to be the next Friday
}
```

`isFriday13` is declare as:

```
private static boolean isFriday13(LocalDate ld) {
    return ld.getDayOfMonth() == 13 && ld.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.FRIDAY;
}
```

Comment: Very good answer. A tiny detail, I’d find `ld = ld.plusWeeks(1);` slightly more elegant.