# Cucumber/Java validating result dates that were 3 months ago

Tags: css, selenium, gherkin, cucumber-java

I'm new to Cucumber/java framework. I'm trying to validate information on a webpage that contains the month that is dated back 3 months ago. So for example:
1. I search for some information.
2. I filter it back for 3 months. 
3. Do a assert to verify that my filter displays results dated back 3 months ago. There is a column in the webpage that displays the date mm/dd/yy. So I need to create a method to verify that the date is 3 months ago validating for month and/or year?

```java
    @Then("Verify that the filtered results display information dated back 90 days")
        **public void verifyFilterBuilds90Days() { assert dashBoardPage.verifyFilterBuilds90Days();** }


    public int verifyFilterBuilds90Days(){
            Calendar calMinus3Months = Calendar.getInstance();
            calMinus3Months.add(Calendar.MONTH, -3);
            return Calendar.MONTH;
        }
```

Comment: I am sorry, that is not clear. Could you provide an example of data that would be OK on your web page and one example of data that would not be OK? And maybe also see if you can make your explanation preciser.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calendar.Month gives wrong output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451872/calendar-month-gives-wrong-output)

Comment: @OleV.V. I was able to update my description.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

Are you after something like this?

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uu");

    String dateFromWebPage = "10/21/19";

    String expected = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .minusMonths(3)
            .format(dateFormatter);

    if (dateFromWebPage.equals(expected)) {
        System.out.println("They agree");
    } else {
        System.out.println("They do not agree");
    }
```

When I ran this code just now, the output was:

> They agree

Be aware, though:

- If midnight passes between the web page is generated and the time you run your test, the date no longer agrees.
- If the web server and your computer use different time zones, the date will probably not always agree.
- Worst, “3 months ago” is not always well-defined. What is 3 months back from May 31? It can’t be February 31 because there are only 28 or 29 days in February.

I suppose the bullet-proof test would generate between 1 and 3 or 4 or 5 dates that would be acceptable taking these points into account and be satisfied if just one of them was actually printed on the web page. For example:

```
    // Assume that the web page has been generated within the last hour
    LocalDate earliestExpected = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.MIN)
            .minusHours(1)
            .toLocalDate()
            .minusMonths(3);
    LocalDate latestExpected = LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.MAX)
            .minusMonths(3);
    System.out.println("Expected interval: " + earliestExpected + " - " + latestExpected);

    LocalDate actual = LocalDate.parse(dateFromWebPage, dateFormatter);
    if (actual.isBefore(earliestExpected) || actual.isAfter(latestExpected)) {
        System.out.println("They do not agree");
    } else {
        System.out.println("They agree");
    }
```

When I ran this snippet just now (in the morning of Jan 22 in my time zone), the output was:

> ```
> Expected interval: 2019-10-21 - 2019-10-22
> They agree
> ```

If we run it in the middle of the day UTC on March 1 in a non-leap year, the expected date interval may include November 28, 29 and 30 and December 1 and 2 (all in the previous year) because at that time there will be places on Earth where it is still February 28 and other places where it is already March 2. If we run it close to midnight between May 31 and June 1, the expected interval will include just February 28 and March 1 because java.time defines 3 months back from May 31 to be the last day of February.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: Thanks, I'll share what I ended up doing, but what you provided is similar to how I created mine. Like you mentioned, I do need to consider how I should proceed with generating the days since I can't validate which exact date the results are displaying. Perhaps generate atleast 30 days and validate if it exists in that month that is dated back 3 months

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. I got an idea for such a tolerant test and added one more code snippet to the answer. You may adjust it to your needs.